# How to implement common interface for multiple API?

Tags: angular, interface, endpoints

I have completed implementing RestAPI for my application. Now I am trying to develop front-end app with Angular. Each RestAPI returns an individual JSON object. Rather than implementing each call to individual RestAPI for each http request, is there any way to implement one single interface to make RestAPI calls nicely? Specifically, in the following,

```
this.http.get('http://a.b.c/api/people/1').subscribe(json => makePerson(json));
this.http.get('http://a.b.c/api/animal/1').subscribe(json => makeAnimal(json));
this.http.get('http://a.b.c/api/flower/1').subscribe(json => makeFlower(json));
```

There are two different methods here, but can I generate one interface to embrace those 3 method calls by passing in API URL and class name?

```
this.call_restapi(url, 'Person');
this.call_restapi(url, 'Animal');
this.call_restapi(url, 'Flower');
```

Could you please give some idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a switch statement in your subscriber, and use an argument to navigate the GET request and switch statement.

```
  get(type: string) {
    const url: string = 'http://a.b.c/api/' + type + '/1';
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(
    (json) => {
      switch(type) {
        case('people'):
          this.makePerson(json));
          break;
        case('animal'):
          this.makeAnimal(json));
          break;
        case('flower'):
          this.makeFlower(json);
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }

    });
  }
```

Comment: Wow! To go further, is there any way to handle this without any restriction like any rule? what I mean by that is that I do not want to put any rule in the api url. I just want to receive the JSON object from the same api url as passed in. The point in this question is more relevant with that there is a way to create object dynamically with variables?

Comment: I don't think so, but assuming it's possible, this doesn't sound like an ideal solution because it could lead to overly complexed processing. Maybe you're overthinking your problem, what's the real end goal here?

Comment: What I am thinking is that I create map with key and value being class name ('people', 'animal', 'flower') and object type (People, Animal, Flower), respectively. A returned JSON object will be mapped to corresponding object according to the class name passed in. So, I want to avoid implementing individual RestAPI call. I want to to solve in just one function. Is this weird?